# Sorting based on aggregate in QGIS Atlas layout

Tags: qgis, atlas, aggregate

In an Atlas layout, I can in a text field or table with no problem sum the attribute SBT for features being inside the current atlas feature by using this aggregate function:

```
aggregate( 
  layer:='Res_FNM_561_V4',
  aggregate:='sum',
  expression:="SBT",
  filter:= within (@geometry , @atlas_geometry )
)
```

I would also like to sort the pages of the atlas by the same sum of SBT but if I use exactly the same formula in the atlas "Sort by" form it returns value zero. Problem is the filtering - if I set `filter:=1` instead I get the sum for all features.

Is it the `@geometry` that refers to something else in this situation?

Comment: It seems to be buggy. When I first tested your expression it worked fine. Now it is not sorting the pages as it was before, even after regenerating the Atlas, clearing and re-entering the expression or by closing and re-opening QGIS. Changing the coverage layer also made the page number stick on a feature id of a feature in a different layer after changing the layer back. Looks like not all the right signals are being fired / caught.